# check auth session in controller

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, authentication

I have used Auth component in my cakephp site. I want to check whether auth session is there or not from controller.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access Auth component by `$this->Auth` from the controller.

`$this->Auth->user()` will give you the [currently authenticated user](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1255/AuthComponent-Methods#user-1264). The information is taken from the session. If this method returns null, the user is not logged in.